# Full height navbar links in a list

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/FbADY/5/

I am wondering what is the proper, semantic way of making my navigation links extend the full height of the navigation bar with the text vertically centered.

I tried setting the a link with a `line-height` the same as the navbar but it didn't affect the height of the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to add:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

and

```
.navigation li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:60px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

You can find a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/FbADY/8/

Comment: The only reason this is somewhat working is because you increased the font-size alot which is not a good sollution.

Comment: Why not? the nav link has the proper height and the font-size can have the whatever height he wants. I set font-size:40px just to highlight where he can set the size of plain text...

Comment: But if I were to change the font size in your fiddle to say `12px` the  links will not take up the entire height of the `header` div. The code in your fiddle would work if you were to add `display: block` to `.navigation li a` thus taking advantage of the `line-height`. Without this the line-height will not take effect. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.navigation li a {
    display: block;
    height:60px; /* same as header */
    line-height:60px; /* same as header */
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbADY/6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have requirement like this, then simply add margin to li and padding to a href.

[image]

```
li {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 20px 5px 15px;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 15px 5px 15px;    
}
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FbADY/9/)